# VMware private internal network

Tags: networking, vmware, private, host

I have 4 virtual machines, a client using windows 7 and 3 servers, one of which is a core server installation the other two are standard windows servers. I need to give all machines a static IP address from the range 192.168.0.0/24 and make sure they are all on a private internal network called intnet.

Can anyone give me general guidelines on how I would go about doing this?? As in how to actually set up a private internal network for these machines and then assign each VM to this network?? I am assuming that the network is created in the client windows 7 machine and then the servers are added to this network but i can't seem to find basic information on how to go about this on the net.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare already does all this for you.

It creates:

- Two internal subnets
- a virtual IP address in the first subnet that is bridged to a real NIC of the host.
- an IP address for each VM in the second subnet.
- routing between the two subnets.

There is a program called 'Manage virtual networks' that does what it says.

Comment: Where can you find this in VMWare? I can't see 'Manage virtual networks' anywhere and the network adapter in settings doesn't give any information.